# angularjs filter only required text message

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have following code which prints `1.57 lakh View More Details`

```
<h4> Price: {{Object.price}}</h4>
```

Would like to print only `1.57 lakh` instead of printing all extra data.
Can we use filters here to eliminate extra data? if yes, How can we achieve this or are there any methods to achieve this?

Comment: Can you not just do `<h4> Price: {{Object.price.replace(" View More Details","")}}</h4>`

Comment: I think you can write custom filter. You can find more details https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a string that changes you can use regex to select the last part of the string

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.price = "1.57 lakh View More Details";

    $scope.replaceText = function(text) {
      return text.replace(/View \w* Details/g, "");
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h4> Price: {{replaceText(price)}}</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks George, this works what if i have a string that changes very frequently ex: `View April details` or `view March details`. Here April and March are the strings changes frequently.. Can we use regular expressions here?? ex: `view * details`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and use `split` to get the relevant data and return it.

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.price = "1.57 lakh View More Details";

$scope.removeText = function(text){
return text.split('lakh')[0]+'lakh';
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 {{removeText(price)}}
</div>
```

Or you can create a custom filter like this also

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.price = "1.57 lakh View More Details";

 
})
.filter('removeText',function(){
  return function(item){
    return item.split('lakh')[0]+'lakh';
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 {{price | removeText}}
</div>
```